# On 13.10 mint graphic periodically freezes after recent updates

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia

laptop lenovo idea pad u430p, Linux Mint 16. Like I said in the title occasionally graphic freezes while all other systems continue to work normally (music plays, for example). Sometimes it unfreezes after minute or so, sometimes not and I had to hard reset the machine.

lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3800
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
        Memory at b5000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]                                                                                   
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]                                                                      
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-                                                    
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2                                                                 
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features                                                                      
        Kernel driver in use: i915                                                                                    

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 09)                                                          
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978                                                                                 
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 68                                                             
        Memory at b5610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]                                                      
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2                                                                 
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-                                                    
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00                                           
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel                                                                           

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])                      
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
        Memory at b5600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 65
        Memory at b5618000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67
        Memory at b5614000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
        Memory behind bridge: b5500000-b55fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: b5400000-b54fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
        Memory behind bridge: b4000000-b4ffffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b2000000-00000000b2ffffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=09, subordinate=09, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
        Memory behind bridge: b3000000-b3ffffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000b1ffffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
        Memory at b561c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61
        I/O ports at 6088 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 6094 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 6080 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 6090 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 6060 [size=32]
        Memory at b561b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3978
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
        Memory at b5619000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at 6040 [size=32]

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 62
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
        Memory at b5504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at b5500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [178] #1e
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 66
        Memory at b5400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 0c-8b-fd-ff-ff-b4-c8-41
        Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [154] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3800
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 63
        Memory at b3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

uname -a

```
Linux laptop 3.13.2-031302-generic #201402061638 SMP Thu Feb 6 21:39:32 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have nouveau driver installed:

```
    dmesg | grep nouveau
[    1.690417] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    1.690747] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:09:00.0] BOOT0  : 0x108100a1
[    1.690749] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:09:00.0] Chipset: GK208 (NV108)
[    1.690750] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:09:00.0] Family : NVE0
[    1.692604] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] checking PRAMIN for image...
[    1.693697] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] ... signature not found
[    1.693700] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] checking PROM for image...
[    1.693771] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] ... signature not found
[    1.693773] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] checking ACPI for image...
[    2.426007] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] ... appears to be valid
[    2.426012] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] using image from ACPI
[    2.426139] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] BIT signature found
[    2.426143] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] version 80.28.25.00.25
[    2.426612] nouveau  [ DEVINIT][0000:09:00.0] adaptor not initialised
[    2.426615] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:09:00.0] running init tables
[    2.489085] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: irq 63 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.489095] nouveau  [     PMC][0000:09:00.0] MSI interrupts enabled
[    2.489134] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:09:00.0] RAM type: DDR3
[    2.489136] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:09:00.0] RAM size: 2048 MiB
[    2.489138] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:09:00.0]    ZCOMP: 0 tags
[    2.489204] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:09:00.0] GPC0: 0x4188ac 0x00000001 (0x1c70822e)
[    2.493775] nouveau  [    VOLT][0000:09:00.0] GPU voltage: 600000uv
[    2.516824] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:09:00.0] FAN control: none / external
[    2.516829] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:09:00.0] fan management: automatic
[    2.516831] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:09:00.0] internal sensor: yes
[    2.516856] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:09:00.0] 07: core 405 MHz memory 405 MHz 
[    2.516900] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:09:00.0] 0a: core 405-875 MHz memory 810 MHz 
[    2.516958] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:09:00.0] 0f: core 405-875 MHz memory 1001 MHz 
[    2.517040] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:09:00.0] --: core 405 MHz memory 405 MHz 
[    2.517150] nouveau  [     DRM] VRAM: 2048 MiB
[    2.517151] nouveau  [     DRM] GART: 1048576 MiB
[    2.517164] nouveau E[     DRM] Pointer to TMDS table invalid
[    2.517797] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB version 4.0
[    2.517798] nouveau E[     DRM] Pointer to flat panel table invalid
[    2.518615] nouveau  [     DRM] ACPI backlight interface available, not registering our own
[    2.518666] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.1.1 20120801 for 0000:09:00.0 on minor 0
[  471.927416] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:09:00.0] GPC0: 0x4188ac 0x00000001 (0x1870822e)
```

What can I do to further investigate the issue?

Comment: blacklist nouveau

Comment: @mikeserv won't graphics just stop working without driver?

Comment: Nope. You have an nvidia/intel hybrid. The freeze you're experiencing is probably happening when the power-save features kick-off and the more powerful nvidia card kicks on. This is an issue with a very sordid history in Linux, but if you're going to try to use it at all, you're going to need the closed-source nvidia driver. In any case, the on-chip Haswell graphics acceleration won't stop functioning.

Comment: @mikeserv is it possible to tell which graphic card (intel or nvidia) currently in use? I occasionally play some games on linux

Comment: Well, if you do, you'll definitely want the closed-source nvidia driver - as of now nouveau cannot affect clock-speed on 600+. This a large part of your problem -the crux of the biscuit, as Zappa might say - obviously you can't ramp up from 0 if you can't ramp up. Anyway, I'm not totally sure about how'd you'd do such a thing with nouveau - probably there's a way. But the nvidia drivers will definitely come with tools to that can provide that information.

Comment: mikeserv makes a good point though blacklisting nouveau won't be enough. Have a look at this guide from the arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA.

Comment: Incidentally you can dump the SMBIOS data out using the `dmidecode` command which can help in shedding light on a system's capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Mikserv's suggestion that the issue here is the driver makes sense. As he points out, you have hybrid graphics and that doesn't work too well under Linux. So, try the following:

1. Install the kernel headers and the nvidia DKMS module

   ```
   sudo aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-kernel-dkms  nvidia-xconfig nvidia-xsettings
   ```
2. Create this file: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` with the following contents:

   Section "Device"
         Identifier "My GPU"
         Driver "nvidia"
   EndSection

   You can do this automatically with these commands:

   ```
   sudo -i
   mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
   echo -e 'Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier "My GPU"\n\tDriver "nvidia"\nEndSection' >> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
   ```
3. Disable graphics switching on your BIOS. There isn't always such a setting but on my thikpad I had something like "OS selection", you need to turn that off and choose the nvidia card instead.
4. Assuming everything went as planned, you can fine tune your settings using `nvidia-xsettings` which was installed in the first step. You can also use nvidia's helper program to create an appropriate xorg.conf:

   sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
   sudo nvidia-xconfig

NOTE: If you can't disable graphics switching, the above may not work and might cause you to boot to a black screen. I recommend you look through these references first:

- https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#configure
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA
- https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee  <== if you have an OPTIMUS card

Comment: Thank you for all the attention and efforts you brought to my question, but it seems that just upgrading kernel (I downloaded deb from ubuntu kernel deb fixed the problem).

Comment: Lol! OK, in that case, could you please write up a quick answer to that effect and accept it? That way other people can know what to do.

Comment: @Moonwalker - thank you for acknowledging one our sites best helpers. It may seem stupid but it really goes along way to those of us that are just trying to help.

Comment: @terdon I'll give it a few more testing days just in case.